# JSoup unable to select QSS Query when called multiple times

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm using JSoup to parse html and retrieve stock price data from marketwatch.com. Using JSoup's demo webpage (https://try.jsoup.org/~xhvAUCZToRTjlv0bIcPwR0S6rJQ) I was able to determine that the stock price is stored in the CSS Query "h3 .value".

In Eclipse, I'm using the following code to retrieve this stock price and then print it. It worked four times initially, but when the series of code is called repeatedly, it starts to simply return nothing (and throws no error). I'm still connected to the internet and the html on the webpage doesn't seem to have changed at all. Am I missing something on the JSoup side of things or is there another way to do this?

```
String baseUrl = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/live";
Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(baseUrl).get();
Elements e = doc.select("h3 .value");
System.out.println(e.text());
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Yserbius it doesn't throw any error. It simply outputs nothing. When I try `e.size()` it returns `0` so it would seem that the QSS Query just isn't correct and returns nothing, but the method worked the very first time I ran it. Is there some way the server is denying my request and the html can't be parsed by JSoup (all without throwing any error)?

Comment: Can you try debugging your code, break on the `System.out`, and see what the value of `e` is ?

Comment: @Yserbius at that breakpoint, `e` is empty. I've found that if I wait a significant period of time (>1 hr) and then run the program again, it works for about 2-3 iterations  (where the value of `e` is the correct stock price) and then breaks down thereafter. It's almost like the method has to "cool down." Is there any chance that the website itself could be blocking my connection?

Comment: If you're running it a lot it's very possible that you're being blocked by the website. Try putting a random wait for a couple of seconds every other call.

Comment: In addition to @Yserbius' suggestion - print the value of `doc` when you encounter the blank value, maybe you'll see something there.

Comment: @Yserbius I was able to make it work pulling data from Google finance instead. I think it must have been some error related to the marketwatch site itself. Appreciate all the help!